# Why is there two different functions GetDpiForSystem and GetDpiForWindow in WinApi?

Tags: windows, winapi, dpi, ppi

Could anyone give some examples when window DPI can differ from system one? Maybe users can somehow specify from outside an application in which DPI it should run. Or maybe it's something else.

Comment: DPI virtualization is practically always turned on, unless the app declares itself to be dpiAware.  And yes, a desktop shortcut for a program permits overriding behavior.  Compatibility tab, "Change high DPI settings" button.

Answer (score 1):

Software can change the [DPI Awareness](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/windef/ne-windef-dpi_awareness) setting(s) for windows created by a specific thread (using the [`SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setthreaddpiawarenesscontext) function), in which case a call to `GetDpiForWindow` for such windows will then give a (potentially) different value than a call to `GetDpiForSystem`.

Further, even within a given thread (or process), one can change the DPI awareness with a call to the aforementioned function, create a new window, then revert to the previous settings and create another window. Then, those two windows will have (possibly) different DPI values from *each other* (depending on whether or not the executable has been built with DPI awareness enabled).

Comment: Can it be changed from outside an application?

Comment: Not sure if it can be changed outside an app (or how) but, certainly, two different apps can have different settings.